# What does" issue''mean in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

*What a morning-fresh as if issued to children on the beach*

from 'Mrs Dalloway'Virginia Woolf

I checked the meaning in the dictionary,
It says'to officially make a statement, give an order,warning'

Answer (score 1):

> What a morning - fresh as if issued to children on the beach

If you look in [Chambers 21st Century Dictionary under *issue*](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=issue&title=21st) you will find:

> **1** to give or send out, distribute, publish or make available, especially officially or formally.
>   **2** (usually issue someone with something) to supply them with the required item, eg an official document.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that should be `What a morning–fresh as if issued to children on the beach.`
The distinction here is the use of an 'em dash' as opposed to a dash or en dash or hyphen, which fools us into thinking it is a hyphenated word, "morning-fresh" (which I kind of like, but that's not what Woolf wrote).

To your question, `fresh as if issued to children at the beach` can simply be rephrased as "fresh as if given to children at the beach".